# Intercepting links in images in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my app, I have a webview, and wanted to open images loaded in a webpage in a separate view controller, which is fine, all I need to do is get the URL to the source of the image & load it in a different view controller, which I can do.

Here is the code I'm using to get the URL to the source of the image.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        NSString *imageSRC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];
        NSString *srcOfImage = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imageSRC];
        NSLog(@"src:%@",srcOfImage);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now, my question is, sometimes, when an image might have a link (i.e.  tag) with it, the webview will load the link while the image opens in my separate view controller. What I would like to do is, stop the webview from opening the link (only the ones in the images) if one exists. Any pointers to how I may go about accomplishing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out, the answer lied in UIWebViewDelegate. For anyone who's interested, here's how I solved it..

```
bool isImage;

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        NSString *imageSRC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];
        NSString *srcOfImage = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imageSRC];
        NSLog(@"src:%@",srcOfImage);
        NSURL *imgsrcURL = [NSURL URLWithString:srcOfImage];
        if (imgsrcURL && imgsrcURL.scheme && imgsrcURL.host) {
            isImage = TRUE;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ((navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) && (isImage)) {
        return NO;
        isImage = FALSE;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```